# PGAdmin locks table

Tags: postgresql

Good afternoon,

I have a problem when editing data in the pgAdmin tables for this specific database, I get a padlock in each column of the table and does not let me edit the values or add new ones, however, if you let me do it through SQL queries in the same program (PGAdmin), so I understand that it is not a permissions problem.

I attach an image of the problem in case someone can help me.

Thank you very much, best regards.

Miguel.

Problem

[image: Problem]

Comment: Do you have a primary key on that table? Some tools require a primary key for editing data.

Comment: Per @FrankHeikens, see [Edit/Browse](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/5.5/editgrid.html) "To modify the content of a table, each row in the table must be uniquely identifiable. If the table definition does not include an OID or a primary key, the displayed data is read only."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a primary key column in the table.

###### to prevent locking in postgreSQL:

- Never add a column with a default value.
- Beware of lock queues, use lock timeouts.
- Create indexes CONCURRENTLY.
- Take aggressive locks as late as possible.
- Adding a primary key with minimal locking.
- Avoid deadlocks by ordering commands.

Answer (score 5):

To clear what the comments are trying to say, lets say you are trying to change a column value by hand.

You got your row with this kind of query.

```
select username, mobilenumber from auth_user where "email" LIKE '%some.user@example.com%'
```

If you run this query, you will get a row. But, you will see a lock icon.
If u want the lock to be removed, change the query to include **'id'**

```
select id, username, mobilenumber from auth_user where "email" LIKE '%some.user@example.com%'
```

Then press F6 to save changes to db.
[image: No locks on columns]

Comment: it deserves more upvotes